# C# DateTimePicker How to set MinValue from specific range to now?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to set MinValue from specific range to now?
I have c# app that allows the user to insert some data to particular database and I want the user to choose and add date and time for some data from range of last month (last 30 days) to now.
I know how to set MaxValue to current time, but I don't know how to set the minimum value to last month!!
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you use the DisplayDateStart and you set it to the current Date - the range you want.

you can also use DisplayDateEnd to set the last date displayed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx